# What does the probability distribution $\mu_P(\lambda)$ represent in Spekken's contextuality?

Tags: contextuality

In ([Spekkens 2005](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.71.052108)), the author defined an "ontological model" as a model that assumes (page 3, above Eq. 4):

1. That every preparation procedure $P$ is associated with a normalised probability density over the ontic state space $\Omega$, that is, some $\mu_P:\Omega\to[0,1]$ such that $\int \mu_P=1$.
2. That every measurement procedure $M$ is associated with a set of indicator functions $\{\xi_{M,k}(\lambda)\}_k$ over the ontic states. Here $k$ label the outcomes, and the functions satisfy $\xi_{M,k}:\Omega\to[0,1]$ and $\sum_k \xi_{M,k}(\lambda)=1$.
3. Some additional things about the "transformation procedure", which I won't focus on here.

My understanding is that in the quantum case, the "preparation procedures" correspond to the quantum states, and $M$ corresponds to the POVM used to measure the state.
In this sense, $\xi_{M,k}$ would seem to just correspond to the rule to obtain outcome probabilities for any given state, that is, $\xi_{M,k}(\lambda)=\operatorname{tr}(M_k\rho_\lambda)$ for some state $\rho_\lambda$ and POVM $M$.

However, what I can't quite figure out is how precisely should I think about $\mu_P$ here.

I kind of thought that I should think of $\lambda$ as the "contextual equivalent" of states $\rho$, but later in the paper, around Eq. (8), they write that "*the assumption of preparation noncontextuality in quantum theory is that the probability distribution over ontic states that is associated with a preparation procedure $P$ depends only on the density operator $\rho$ associated with $P$: $\mu_P(\lambda)=\mu_\rho(\lambda)$*. This confuses me because then clearly a given state $\rho$ can correspond to different $\lambda$, but at the same time it doesn't seem that $\lambda$ should correspond to measurement outcomes, given the previous definition of $\xi_{M,k}$ function and labels $k$.

But also, when first introduced (second column of page 2), they write that *someone who knows that a system was prepared using the preparation procedure $P$ describes the system by a probability density $\mu_P(\lambda)$ over the model variables*. So it would seem that $\lambda\in\Omega$ are "model variables" that somehow characterise the state $\rho$.

So then this leaves me confused. States $\rho$ are represented by "model variables" $\lambda$ via a probability distribution $\mu_\rho(\lambda)$. But this distribution is not the probability distribution corresponding to different measurement outcomes. So what is it exactly? An answer to *[What is a simple example of Spekken's measurement contentextuality?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/33101/55)* would probably also help in figuring out this question.